# Slack Interactive Messages: Button click response

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I've got a question about a problem I'm having with the Slack API. I have some code written that sends a message to a specific channel (via Incoming Webhook) when a ticket is created in our ticketing system. This message has a couple buttons in it which I would like to use to perform actions.

[image]

I have my Response URL set up, pointing to some PHP code that should post a simple message in the same channel when the button is clicked (for testing purposes).

```
<?php 

//Required for ticketing system API, to be implemented later
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';

//get information from HTTP POST, sent at button click
$payload = $_POST['payload'];
$data = json_decode($payload,true);

$responseURL = $data["response_url"];

class Response {
    public $response_type = "";
    public $text = "";
    public $replace_original = "";
}

$r = new Response();
$r->response_type = "in_channel";
$r->text = "Ticket Accepted";
$r->replace_original = "false";

header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Using CURL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $responseURL,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($r)
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($resp);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

I am getting the response URL from the HTTP POST request sent at the button click, but instead of sending my message ("Ticket Accepted"), I get the following as soon as I click the button:

[image]

Also note: I tried setting `replace_original` to `false` so that I could see my original message (with the buttons), but that message is replaced by the message above anyway.

During testing, I tried setting `$responseURL` to an Incoming Webhooks URL for a different channel. When I did that, I **do** get my simple "Ticket Accepted" message in that channel and a similar message replacing the button message:

[image]

I'm not sure why the button clicks are generating these responses right away, but they seem to be keeping me from posting anything else to that channel. Any ideas?

Comment: replace_original should be a boolean, try this: `$r->replace_original = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You reply to a button request just with an echo containig your message. No need to send an explicit message to a webhook.

Your response has to be JSON though. Here is a code example. Replace

```
$message = [
            "response_type" => "in_channel",            
            "text" => "Ticket accepted"
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($message);
```

The reason you get that response on Slack is the `var_dump($resp);`. It will echo the content of the variable, which Slack tries to display.

Comment: Does this work? I just tried to reply the incoming request but got no text "ticket accepted"